# Is it possible to execute http script recorded using JMeter as https?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jmeter

Is it possible to execute http script recorded using JMeter as https. I recorded the script from the server where the link is posted as http. Now, I have to run it in another server where it is posted as https. Will I have to record the script again in https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you already recorded the script, the simplest thing to do is to replace (e.g. within some text editor) the occurences of

```
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
```

with

```
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
```

in the JMX file.

In future recording, it is best to add to the "Test Script Recorder" element a "HTTP Request Defaults" with "http" value of "Protocol" — this way the protocol field will be empty in recorded samplers. See also: "Handling of HTTP Request Defaults" on http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder.